# Tail $\sigma$-algebra and transition invariant events.

Tags: probability, measure-theory

I have the following exercise:

Let $\Omega=\left\{0,1\right\}^{\infty}$ and $\mathcal{F}$ the cylynders sigma algebra on $\Omega$. The function $\varphi\left(\omega_1,\omega_2,\ldots\right)=\left(\omega_2,\omega_3,\ldots\right)$ defined on $\Omega$ is called a shift. An event $A\in\mathcal{F}$ is said to be *shift invariant* if $\varphi^{-1}\left(A\right)=A$. Let $\mathcal{C}$ be the class of shift-invariant events in $\mathcal{F}$. Show $\mathcal{C}$ is a sigma algebra. Let $A_n=\left\{\omega\in\Omega:\omega_n=1\right\}$. Show that $\mathcal{C}$ is not included in the tail sigma-algebra of $\left(A_n\right)_n$.

Having been able to show that $\mathcal{C}$ is indeed a sigma-algebra and that it contains the events $\liminf_n A_n$ and $\limsup_n A_n$, I was not able to show the last point, i.e. I can't exhibit an event which is shift invariant but does not belong to the tail sigma-algebra.

I would really appreciate a hint in order to visualize the problem better!

Comment: Try an event that depends on all the coordinates.

Comment: That was my initial strategy. But can an event that depends on all coordinates be transition invariant ?? If I add a random first coordinate to every singleton, the property of such singleton will change if it depends on all coordinates, no?

Comment: $A$ above is a singleton, and it I think it isn't shift invariant. Indeed $\varphi^{-1}\left(\omega\right)=\left\{0,1\right\}\times\left\{1\right\}^{\infty}$ $ \neq\omega$

Comment: Yes..  you are defining shift-invariant  based on the PRE-IMAGE by the shift operator, that is, $\varphi^{-1}\left(A\right)=A$.  On the other hand, the "usual definition" of shift-invariant is $\varphi\left(A\right)=A$.

Comment: Unfortunately this is the exercise I was given :) Could you give me a reference for the definition of "shift-invariant"?

Comment: There are plenty of references where "$T$-invariant"  means $T(A)=A$ or $T(A) \subseteq A$.  And that applies to any transformation $T$, not only the shift operator.  

For instance, in Linear Operators, Hilbert or Banach spaces, when we say that a subspace $W$ is $T$-invariant,  we mean $T(W) \subseteq W$.

Comment: May I ask you where your exercise came from?

Comment: Just a type-set homework. Thanks a lot !

Comment: I agree to Brian: either the statement or the conclusion of this exercise is incorrect. I see three possibilities: 

 1. The definition of "shift-invariant" would be $A \in \mathcal{F}$ and $\phi(A)=A$, then $\mathcal{C}$  must be the $\sigma$-algebra generated by the shift-invariant events and the conclusion is correct. Just take $A$ to have a single element such that all entries are $1$, then $A\in \mathcal{C}$ and $A$ is not in the tail $\sigma$-algebra.

Comment: 2. The definition of "shift-invariant" would be  $\phi^{-1}(A)=A$, but would NOT require $A \in \mathcal{F}$, then  the conclusion is correct. In fact in this case, $\mathcal{C}$  is not even included in $\mathcal{F}$.
 3. The definition of "shift-invariant" is exactly as stated, that is $A \in \mathcal{F}$ and $\phi^{-1}(A)=A$, then the conclusion is NOT correct.  In this case, it is easy to see that $\mathcal{C}$ is included tail $\sigma$-algebra (see Brian's answer for a short and nice proof).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Either the statement or the conclusion of this exercise is incorrect.

With your definition of a shift-invariant set $A$, you have $\omega\in A$ if and only if $\varphi(\omega)\in A$. Thus, by induction, for all $n\geq 1$ you have $\omega\in A$ if and only if $\varphi^n(\omega)\in A$. This gives 
$$A=\{\omega: \varphi^n(\omega)\in A\}\in\sigma(A_n, A_{n+1},\dots).$$
Taking the intersection over $n$ shows that $A$ belongs to the tail $\sigma$-algebra.

Comment: Yes, I agree: either the statement or the conclusion of this exercise is incorrect.